# Is it possible to limit the maximum io_unit size generated by FIO benchmarking tool?

Tags: linux, kernel, disk

I want to run in configuration where writes are at most 64KB in size.

Answer (score 0):

(This isn't the right site for this type of question because it's not about programming - [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) look more appropriate)

> I want to run in configuration where writes are at most 64KB in size.

Isn't that what the [`blocksize` parameter](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#block-size) does? For example:

```
fio --filename=/tmp/fio.tmp --size=128k --bs=64k --rw=write --name=example
```

Creates a file 128KiB big but then writes two 64KiB I/Os to it (but be aware the filesystem/block layer may modify requests before they are submitted to the disk).

If you meant "I'd like to write a range of different sized I/Os with 64KiB being the maximum" then take a look at the [`blocksize_range`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-blocksize-range) and/or [`bssplit`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-bssplit) parameters.